# Passing Multiple Values to a Command in PowerShell

Tags: arrays, powershell, command-line, arguments

I'm trying to pass an array of arguments to a command in PowerShell.
I'm not sure how to tell it to loop through the arguments and execute the code properly.

Here is my array example:

```
$values = {value1, value2, value3...}
```

Here is my command example:

```
dosomething -a value1 -a value2 -a value3
```

I tried using a foreach but I just can't figure out the syntax.

```
dosomething {foreach($value in $values) {-a $value}}
```

I feel like I'm very close but missing something.

Comment: try with `dosomething @(foreach($value in $values) { '-a', $value })`

Comment: Curly braces are a scriptblock in powershell, not an array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> `$values = {value1, value2, value3...}`

Unless `value1`, etc. are *placeholders* for *numbers* (e.g., `42`) or *strings* (e.g., `'foo'`), this is *invalid syntax*, given that **`{ ... }` creates a [script block](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Script_Blocks)**, the content of which must be valid PowerShell source code, and the result of which is a *piece of PowerShell code* meant for *later execution on demand*, such as with `&`, the [call operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Operators#call-operator-) or `.`, the [dot-sourcing operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Operators#dot-sourcing-operator-)

In order **to create an *array*, simply use [`,`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Operators#comma-operator-) to separate the elements** or enclose them in **`@(...)`, the [array-subexpression operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Operators#array-subexpression-operator--)**:

```bash
$values = 'value1', 'value2', 'value3' # , ...

# explicit alternative
$values = @( 'value1', 'value2', 'value3' )
```

The fact that **you're looking to pass *multiple* `-a` arguments implies that you're calling an *external program***:

- *PowerShell-native commands* do *not* allow targeting a given parameter multiple times.

**When *calling external programs*, you can *pass both parameter *names* and *values* as a flat array of string arguments***:

- With a **given array (collection)**, it's easiest to use the [intrinsic **`.ForEach()` method**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Arrays#foreach):

```bash
# Note: Assumes that `doSomething` is an *external program*
dosomething $values.ForEach({ '-a', $_ })
```

- Alternatively, **you may use `@(...)` or - in this case, interchangeably - `$(...)`, the [subexpression operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Operators#subexpression-operator--) to pass the output from *arbitrary commands* as *individual arguments***:

```bash
# Note: Assumes that `doSomething` is an *external program*

# Using a pipeline.
dosomething $($values | ForEach-Object { '-a', $_ })

# Using a foreach statement.
dosomething $(foreach ($value in $values) { '-a', $value })
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you Santiago Squarzon!

here is my working code concept:

```
$zones = {domain.com, domain.net, domain.ect...}
certbot @(foreach ($zone in $zones) { '-d', $zone})
```

as an extra step I can can import and convert the zones from a csv file (example zones.csv):

```
Sites
domain.com
domain.net
domain.ect
```

Then import and convert the Sites to an array in PowerShell:

```
$zones = Import-csv -Path zones.csv

$zones = foreach ($site in $zones.sites) {$site}
```

Comment: Don't use `{ ... }` if you want to create _arrays_. Also, it's generally best to stick with the premise of the question in terms of variable names (`$values`) and parameter names (`-a`).